# ¿Cómo puedo crear una estructura básica para probar spring-boot con testng?

Tags: spring-boot, test-ng

Quiero crear un Hola Mundo de Spring-Boot junto con TestNG usando maven.

Se que requiero estas dos dependencias

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a JUnit el proyecto con TestNG tiene diferencias:

La clase de pruebas debe heredar de: AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests basicamente se peude decir que esto remplaza el tag @RunWith de Junit.

Las dependencias usadas quedaron así:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

La última dependencia de [Asserj](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) es opcional, solo para hacer el código más legible

El código realizado se puede ver [acá](https://github.com/tutmosisII/HolaMundoSpringRestTestNG)